# Which information a site can get when scraped by a scrapy spider?

Tags: python, scrapy, web-crawler

I have a Single file spider which crawls only a site. Which informations can the owner of the site can see?

Here, I am not using custom settings. (So that's default setting).

Example:

1.Spider name

2.IP

3.OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The site owner can see this info.

1. Spider name. You can change the to anything you want
2. IP address you can use a VPN or proxies to change it.
3. Browser you are using. To change this go to settings and go look for `USER_AGENT`
   remove the comment and you can easily go on google to search for other user-agents.
4. Cookies. Scrapy has cookies enables by default. Go to settings and look for `COOKIES_ENABLED` Remove the comment so it is set to False. This would make the scraping job more stealthy.
5. Concurrent_Requests. This is so also in the settings. It is how many requests you make simultaneously. It is better to lower the number so it is more friendly to the website.

Comment: My spider consists of only one file.So how can I do what you said in above on my file? I don't want to use default structure.

Comment: When you create a project on scrapy, you have other files created. Go to the setting.py file. And change. For user_agents you can easily google other user_agent examples. For cookies uncomment it and make it COOKIES_ENABLED =True  . For concurrent requests uncomment it and change the number to a lower number, anything you want.